# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Dynamic' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I am working on a .Net project 3.5 framework. I am getting this error while run time.

I think that this System.Dynamic resides in System.Core DLL, but I cannot find System.Dynamic under System.core?

How can I add this in my project?

Answer (score 2):

[`System.Dynamics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.aspx) is not available in .NET 3.5 - the DLR (= Dynamic Language Runtime) was introduced with .NET 4.0 and is not availalbe as a backport AFAIK.

The DLR and `System.Dynamics` are required to use the `dynamic` type. If you want to use that, you need to upgrade to at least .NET 4.0.

Comment: Thanks chrfin for swift response.
But at runtime the error msg is showing,

Comment: Maybe it is dynamically loaded by some library you are using?

Comment: thanks once again
So what is the solution of the error  
I want to know how to fix the error?

Comment: As said in the answer: Upgrade to .NET 4.0 or 4.5

Comment: Its not possible for as of now
any other suggestion ?

Comment: No, NOT possible! Either upgrade the FW or do not use `dynamic` (or the library which does)...

Comment: Actually i the same code runs on a server and the same code when deployed on another server it is giving that error atually the entire .net structure is same